# How to expand the following brackets, taking into consideration that I need to eventually get rid of the term $\frac 1{n+m}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following brackets where $a>-1/2$, $n$ and $m$ are two different sample sizes, $x,y\geq 0$:
$$(x+\frac{1}{n+m})^{-a}-(y+\frac{1}{n+m})^{-a}$$ 
I need to expand the bracket in a way that cancels out the term $+\frac{1}{n+m}$ .

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: I have edit it a bit and I already have it in question form not to be rude

Comment: Why do you believe such an expansion and cancellation exists?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can do is: $$(x+\frac{1}{n+m})^{-a}-(y+\frac{1}{n+m})^{-a}=\left(\frac{x(n+m)+1}{m+n}\right)^{-a}-\left(\frac{y(n+m)+1}{m+n}\right)^{-a}=\frac{1}{(m+n)^{-a}}(xn+xm+1)^{-a}-\frac{1}{(m+n)^{-a}}(yn+ym+1)^{-a}=\frac{(m+n)^a}{(xn+xm+1)^a-(yn+ym+1)^a}$$

Answer (score 0):

Factor out $\frac{1}{n+m}$ from each bracket and expand what is inside using the binomial theorem.